# git-p4 sync not working - mysterious stack trace

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

I'm trying to use git-p4 to clone perforce depot.  I keep running into a problem in the git-p4 script, where git-p4 tries to access a dict key that is not defined and throws a trace.

```
[~/p4/prod@ernie02] (master) $ 
git p4 sync --verbose --use-client-spec //depot/prod/
Reading pipe: git config git-p4.user
Reading pipe: git config git-p4.password
Reading pipe: git config git-p4.port
Reading pipe: git config git-p4.host
Reading pipe: git config git-p4.client
p4 -u mkramer -c mkramer -G client -o
Opening pipe: p4 -u mkramer -c mkramer -G client -o
None
Doing initial import of //depot/prod/ from revision #head into refs/remotes/p4/master
p4 -u mkramer -c mkramer -G files //depot/prod/...#head
Opening pipe: p4 -u mkramer -c mkramer -G files //depot/prod/...#head
commit into refs/remotes/p4/master
p4 -u mkramer -c mkramer -G -x - print
Opening pipe: p4 -u mkramer -c mkramer -G -x - print
p4 -u mkramer -c mkramer -G users
Opening pipe: p4 -u mkramer -c mkramer -G users
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mkramer/git/bin/git-p4", line 1922, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/mkramer/git/bin/git-p4", line 1917, in main
    if not cmd.run(args):
  File "/home/mkramer/git/bin/git-p4", line 1651, in run
    self.importHeadRevision(revision)
  File "/home/mkramer/git/bin/git-p4", line 1461, in importHeadRevision
    self.commit(details, self.extractFilesFromCommit(details), self.branch, self.depotPaths)
  File "/home/mkramer/git/bin/git-p4", line 1063, in commit
    data = file['data']
KeyError: 'data'
```

I went into the script and printed out the file dict right at that point and got some more details, which I'll revise for clarity & anonymity.  The faulty dict looked like this:

```
{'action': 'move/delete', 'path': '//depot/prod/foo/bar', 'rev': '3', 'type': 'xtext'}
```

My p4 client looks like this:

```
Client: mkramer
Update: 2010/04/27 14:46:10
Access: 2010/04/27 14:51:29

Owner:  mkramer
Description:
        Created by mkramer.
Root:   z:\p4
AltRoots:
        z:\p4
        /home/mkramer/p4
Options:        noallwrite noclobber nocompress unlocked nomodtime normdir
SubmitOptions:  submitunchanged
LineEnd:        share
View:

        //depot/prod/... //mkramer/prod/...
        -//depot/.../foo/... //mkramer/.../foo/...
```

As you can see, the faulty dict is a file that does not exist in my client view.  I believe this is the source of the problem.  However, I am clearly running the command with --use-client-spec.  I've also tried `git config git-p4.useclientspec true` 
The verbose output makes it look like it's pulling my view out of

```
Opening pipe: p4 -u mkramer -c mkramer -G client -o.
```

If I run `p4 -u mkramer -c mkramer client -o` I see the correct view.

If I run `p4 -u mkramer -c mkramer files //depot/prod/...#head` I see files that aren't in my view.

Versions of my software:

```
[~/p4/prod@ernie02] (master) $ p4 -V
Perforce - The Fast Software Configuration Management System.
Copyright 1995-2009 Perforce Software.  All rights reserved.
Rev. P4/LINUX26X86_64/2009.1/205670 (2009/06/29).
[~/p4/prod@ernie02] (master) $ git --version
git version 1.7.0.5
[~/p4/prod@ernie02] (master) $ python -V
Python 2.6.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We just ran into this ourselves.  P4 appears to have added some new commands last year that git-p4 doesn't fully support; particularly "move/delete" and "move/add".

In order to work around the issue, we changed the line:

```
if file["action"] in ("delete", "purge"):
```

to:

```
if file["action"] in ("delete", "purge", "move/delete"):
```

So far this is working for us, but I won't assert that this is necessarily a robust fix.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that was fixed in recent versions of git-p4 using essentially the patch provided by rbergman.  See http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=commit;h=562d53fa69933b3ade2691b99cbe67722313f43c for more details; this patch probably appeared in one of the later 1.6.x releases and is definitely in the 1.7.x releases of git.